# Jquery Ajax Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, autocomplete

I am trying to implement an autocomplete form of cities, with a webserver where the JSON array and a autocomplete function are located that returns a JSON array of completions for a city name from the array of cities, but I don't seem to get any response from my Ajax call. Is there something wrong with my Ajax call?

I am trying to submit my form data called "term" into the url "/suggestjson" , and then display the returned JSON in the body of the html file

I know the webserver works because typing "localhost:8000/suggestjson?term=a" into the browser returns all the cities starting with "a" (such as Adelaide), click http://postimg.org/image/gki6kct23/ to see it

HTML form

```
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <fieldset><legend>Cities</legend>
  <input type='text' name='city' id='city'>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var term = $('input[name=city]');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/suggestjson",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: term,
        success: function (data) {
            $("body").append(data);
        }    
    }); 
});
```

Webserver

```
cities = ['New York', 'London', 'Los Angeles', 
          'Paris', 'San Francisco', 'Adelaide']

if environ['PATH_INFO'] == "/suggestjson":
    return suggest_json_application(environ, start_response)


def suggest_json_application(environ, start_response):
    //Return JSON array of completions for a city name

    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'], environ=environ)

    if form.has_key('term'):
        q = form.getvalue("term", "")
        matches = [i for i in cities if i.startswith(q)]
    else:
        matches = []

    return json.dumps(matches)
```

Comment: Try: `var term = $('input[name=city]').val()`; also, `data: {'term': term}`

Comment: yup, but eventually you have to give the value not the dom node to the ajax submit.

Comment: do you see any 500s in the console? Also, what is `start_response` ?

Comment: One more question - if you do `print json.dumps(matches)` does it give right answer?

Comment: that means that is where the error is. Debug the program to see if the input is coming through right. what does `form.has_key('term')` output ?

Comment: I meant on the console

Comment: sure, you could use pastebin or codepad and share the link

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the `data` property correctly, try creating an object with the value of the input:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/suggestjson",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {term: term.val()}, //get the value of the input and put it in a data object
    success: function (data) {
        //data here are the results coming from the server, format this as HTML and then append
       var htmlData = ''
       .... formatting here ....
       $('body').append(htmlData);

    }    
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your javascript console? Alsoyou're also trying to append a javascript array to the body. `append()` should take HTML, so you'll need to format your results in the success handler.

Answer (score 2):

Have you confirmed that `/suggestion` yields the JSON that you expect? Can you paste the result?

Your `term` should be `var term = $("input[name=city]").val()` and your `data` should be `data: 'term='+term`

Comment: ![Image of Results](http://postimg.org/image/gki6kct23/)

Here is an image of the results I get from "localhost:8000/suggestjson?term=a", there are more results since the original array is much larger than shown in the code above